# Robot framework Drop down list Selection

Tags: robotframework

I’m having few drop-downs in a page where I have to selected a name which is 17th number in the list drop-down and this name is not visible on the page it needs to be scroll down on the drop-down menu to see it.

I tried for one drop down by clicking on the drop down to open then use `Scroll Element in to View` keyword as `Scroll Element Into View //div[@role=‘listbox’]//div[text()='John, Doe (5611234) ']`. It worked but for another drop-down this is not working.

I also tried to extract all values from list using
`${list}= Get Element attribute //div[@role=‘listbox’]//div[@class=“v-list-item__title”] text`, `select from list keyword by value` but all returning no values for this code but in Selectors hub it matches and show this xpath has 20 items which is the items in the drop-down . Please see the code snippet below:

```html
<div class="v-menu_content theme-light menuable_content_active v-autocomplete_content" style="max-height: 340px; win-width:67p...
<div role="listbox" tabindex="-1" class="v-list v-select-list v-sheet theme--light v-list--dense theme--light" id="list-235" style>
 <div tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"  id="list-item-299-0" role="option" class "v-list-item--link theme--light">

 :before
<div class=v-list-item-content" xpath="1"
  <div class="v-list-item_title">John, Doe (5021345) </div>
```

I tried for one drop-down by clicking on the drop-down to open then use  `Scroll Element in to View` keyword as
`Scroll Element Into View //div[@role=‘listbox’]//div[text()='John, Doe (5611234) ']`. It worked but for another drop-down this is not working.

Comment: could you provide the page URL?

Comment: It;s my work application. you can't access it . Are you able see my code snippet here? I just see only two lines of code here eventhough i pastes  more then this